# What is an on topic question?

Tags: discussion

I just wondered what is on topic on philosophy.stackexchange

I've had quite a few questions closed etc. for this very reason, so obviously it's not clear what it amounts to, as I'm not here to annoy anyone.

In particular, is the burden of proof on someone to show that something isn't philosophy? In effect, it seems that people are apt to close questions for not seeming philosophical enough, when it could at least be suggested that philosophers should answer any question asked of them, rather than be set to just say that it's in some sense a pseudo philosophical question.

---

Perhaps the community should be voting down on questions more than they vote close. For the given reasons (unhelpful / no research / unclear) as I imagine that most reasons for closing meeting those definitions, instead.

Am I right?

Comment: when you say `philosophers should answer any question asked of them,`, this seems to misunderstand that this is an SE about philosophy -- not a place to do philosophy.

Comment: actually that is a fair point @virmaior thanks

Comment: Funny, I often feel the opposite, that there should be less downvoting and more voting to close, since the latter is usually due to technical reasons and is not taken as personally. As for the "burden of proof", SE places none on either type of voting, at least holds come with a generic explanation, downvoting does not require even a comment. "Off-topic" does not usually mean "not philosophy", it can mean too vague, too broad, too personal, etc., for SE format, and I do not think this can be codified with much precision.

Comment: @Conifold what does "too personal" mean if not that? wasn't aware the other reasons were viable ones, thanks